# showing these vector field are linearly independent

Tags: differential-geometry

I need to show that the produc $S^1 \times S^n$ is parallelizable. I allready have the $n+1$ vector fields but I am having trouble proving they are linearly indepedent.

If $y=(y_1,y_2,...,y_{n+1})$ then define $F_k= e_k-y_k·y$. Then $G_k(x,y)= (y_k·ix, -F_k(y)$ are the $n+1$ vector field over $S ^1\times S^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach to show that $S^n\times S^1$ is parallelizable.

Consider $S^n$ as a subset of $R^{n+1}$. The restriction of the tagent space $TR^{n+1}$ of $R^{n+1}$ to $S^n$ is a trivial bundle. The tangent bundle of $S^n\times S^1$ is isomorphic to $TS^n\times TS^1$. $TS^1\simeq S^1\times R$. Consider a generator $e$ of $TS^1$, $e(x)=(x,1)$. The pullback of $TR^{n+1}_{\mid S^n}$ by the projection $p:S^n\times S^1\rightarrow S^n$ is the trivial bundle $S^n\times S^1\times R^{n+1}$ You can define the isomorphism $f:T(S^n\times S^1)\simeq TS^n\times S^1\times R\rightarrow S^n\times S^1\times R^{n+1}$ as follows:

Let $x\in S^n, y\in S^1, u\in TS^n_x, f_{(x,y)}(u,e(y))=(x,y,u+e(y)x)$ where you identifiy $S^n\times S^1\times R^{n+1}$ with the pullback $p^*(TR^{n+1}_{\mid S^n})$.

Comment: yes, thanks, but I needed that specific approach for a homework